# Selenium in Python: Nothing returned after sending in keys and selecting an option

Tags: python, selenium

I am building up a web scraper for this website: [Link](http://app1.sfda.gov.cn/datasearchcnda/face3/base.jsp?tableId=25&tableName=TABLE25&title=%E4%B8%AD%E8%8D%AF&bcId=152904713761213296322795806604). Instead of scraping off all the content, I only need some of them, and that is why I add some search conditions in the "快速查询" form.

The website puts all the key content in JavaScript... Not sure if this is the reason.

```py
driver.get('http://app1.sfda.gov.cn/datasearchcnda/face3/base.jsp?tableId=25&tableName=TABLE25&title=%E4%B8%AD%E8%8D%AF&bcId=152904713761213296322795806604')

s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('s31p0'))
s1.select_by_value('25,152904756797819090327732889259') #the option is 中药
print (s1.first_selected_option.text)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('keyword')
elem.send_keys('注射' + Keys.ENTER) #the key word is 注射

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
js_links = soup.select('a[href^="javascript:"]') #find all the links
print(js_links)
```

Normally, it should return a list of 15  tags like this:
6.龟鹿补肾片 (86903249000087 郑州福瑞堂制药有限公司 国药准字Z20090420)

But after adding all the conditions, it only returns "[]".

Can anyone tell me how should I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out that, after adding the conditions, the main content div shows 'the server doesn't return data.' Is there any way to fix this?
```html
<div id="content"><br/><br/><br/><span style="font-size:x-large;color:#215add">服务器未返回数据</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After entering `'注射` in input box and hitting the enter button, you can use this code :

Code :

```
list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#content table:nth-of-type(2) tr a")
```

This will return you list of all 15 links. You would get anchor tag. You can either iterate over this list like this :

```
for link in list_of_links:
  print(link.text)
```

**EDIT1:**

I'm using this code :

```
driver.get("http://app1.sfda.gov.cn/datasearchcnda/face3/base.jsp?tableId=25&tableName=TABLE25&title=%E4%B8%AD%E8%8D%AF&bcId=152904713761213296322795806604")


s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('s31p0'))
s1.select_by_value('25,152904756797819090327732889259') #the option is 中药
#print (s1.first_selected_option.text)

driver.find_element_by_id('keyword').send_keys("注射") 
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='查询'][name='Submit']").click()


print("after send keys")

list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#content table:nth-of-type(2) tr a")

print("after listing")

for link in list_of_links:
  print(link.text)
```

Console output :

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57271/devtools/browser/600a7596-da33-4d3d-970f-329e731ebfb3
after send keys
after listing
1.龟龙中风丸 (86901343001160 沈阳红药集团股份有限公司 国药准字Z20020147)
2.龟龄集 (86902884000629 山西广誉远国药有限公司 国药准字Z14020687)
3.龟黄补酒 (86901890000654；86901890000661；86901890000678 远大医药黄石飞云制药有限公司 国药准字Z20026072)
4.龟鹿补肾胶囊 (86905098000638 广西华天宝药业有限公司 国药准字Z20123109)
5.龟鹿补肾片 (86900427000075 广东心宝药业科技有限公司 国药准字Z20080217)
6.龟鹿补肾片 (86903249000087 郑州福瑞堂制药有限公司 国药准字Z20090420)
7.龟鹿补肾口服液 (86900291000263 广东华天宝药业集团有限公司 国药准字Z44023432)
8.龟鹿补肾丸 (86900291000270 广东华天宝药业集团有限公司 国药准字Z44022778)
9.龟鹿补肾丸 (86900291000294 广东华天宝药业集团有限公司 国药准字Z44022779)
10.龟鹿补肾丸 (86900415000308 广州花城药业有限公司 国药准字Z44020148)
11.龟鹿益肾胶囊 (86905004000028 湖南康寿制药有限公司 国药准字B20020196)
12.龟鹿滋肾丸 (86900008000272 北京宝树堂科技药业有限公司 国药准字Z11020387)
13.龟鹿滋肾丸 (86905156002598 广西梧州制药(集团)股份有限公司 国药准字Z45020433)
14.龟鹿滋肾丸 (86905156002604 广西梧州制药(集团)股份有限公司 国药准字Z45020432)
15.龟鹿滋肾丸 (86900256000413 国药集团冯了性(佛山)药业有限公司 国药准字Z44023076)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I still get an empty list. After entering '注射', it enters a page without any links. I used 'soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')' to test it.

Comment: I have updated answer, Please let me know any more concerns.

Comment: Thank you! But no, the listing is not what I desired for. I guess your code is alright, but website did something to prevent it from returning the right content? The ideal output would start from this one: "1.消癌平注射液 (86901583000749；86901583000732 南京圣和药业股份有限公司 国药准字Z20025868)." It should contain the key word "注射."

Comment: Ok, we gotta click on `查询` this. That'd solve the issue. But If you are not interested with listing sorry I can't help you beyond that.

Comment: and yes, website prevents to click on `查询 `, and when you try manually with session which was opened with selenium , it returns `服务器未返回数据`, don't know what does that mean.

Comment: 服务器未返回数据 means "the server didn't return data."